# yaml dump of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyyaml

I figured I'd share, since I searched that on SO and couldn't quite find what I needed.

I wanted to dump a `pd.DataFrame` into a yaml file.

`Timestamps` should be shown nicely, not as the default:

```
  date: !!python/object/apply:pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
  - 1589241600000000000
  - null
  - null
```

Also, the output should be correct YaML format, i.e., it should be readable back by `yaml.load`. The output should be reasonably concise, i.e. preferring the 'flow' format.

As an example, here is some data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(
        date=pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - pd.Timedelta('1 day'),
        x=0,
        b='foo',
        c=[1,2,3,4],
        other_t=pd.Timestamp.now(),
    ),
    dict(
        date=pd.Timestamp.now().normalize(),
        x=1,
        b='bar',
        c=list(range(32)),
        other_t=pd.Timestamp.now(),
    ),
]).set_index('date')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. It has some customization of the `Dumper` to handle `Timestamp`. The output is more legible, and still valid yaml. Upon loading, yaml recognizes the format of a valid datetime (ISO format, I think), and re-creates those as `datetime`. In fact, we can read it back into a `DataFrame`, where these `datetime`s are automatically converted into `Timestamp`. After a minor reset of index, we observe that the new `df` is identical to the original.

```
import yaml
from yaml import CDumper
from yaml.representer import SafeRepresenter
import datetime


class TSDumper(CDumper):
    pass

def timestamp_representer(dumper, data):
    return SafeRepresenter.represent_datetime(dumper, data.to_pydatetime())

TSDumper.add_representer(datetime.datetime, SafeRepresenter.represent_datetime)
TSDumper.add_representer(pd.Timestamp, timestamp_representer)
```

With this, now we can do:

```
text = yaml.dump(
    df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records'),
    sort_keys=False, width=72, indent=4,
    default_flow_style=None, Dumper=TSDumper,
)
print(text)
```

The output is relatively clean:

```
-   date: 2020-05-12 00:00:00
    x: 0
    b: foo
    c: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    other_t: 2020-05-13 02:30:23.422589
-   date: 2020-05-13 00:00:00
    x: 1
    b: bar
    c: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
    other_t: 2020-05-13 02:30:23.422613
```

Now, we can load this back:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(yaml.load(text, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)).set_index('date')
```

And (drum roll, please):

```
df2.equals(df)
# True
```